# Does Uncharted 4's cover allow wall banging?

Tags: uncharted-4

Wall banging = using bullets to penetrate through cover to hit enemies that are hiding on the other side of it: http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Bullet_Penetration

I thought that the point of using cover was to avoid getting shot but in multiplayer I seem to keep getting shot even when behind cover. I know that Uncharted 4 has destructible cover, but is it possible to shoot through cover as well (wall bang)?

Many shooters have light/heavy cover and different weapons penetrate it better. Is any info available on the different types of cover Uncharted 4? It would be good to know.

Comment: In most games I've played, "wall bang" has a very different meaning. It means to throw a low fuse-time grenade around a corner so the enemy doesn't have any time to react.

Comment: Really? In CS GO and the Call of Duty series "wall banging" refers to bullet penetration: http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Bullet_Penetration
I will define this in the question though to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you are in cover you are partly exposed to other players. For example, if you're behind low cover and the opponent is a little higher than you, or if you are behind a corner but the opponent is a little bit off to the side.

I don't think your bullets can go through things like walls or stones. For destructible cover, it's possible that some bullets will start going through after the cover object starts to degrade (I'm not sure about that).